# Not sure what I'm doing wrong in this Rails Angular app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am trying to integrate Angular into an existing Rails app.

I only want Angular in the authenticated portions of my app. user_profile, etc

I'm loosely following this post:

http://start.jcolemorrison.com/setting-up-an-angularjs-and-rails-4-1-project/

Right now I'm trying to hit this url to just test that it's working. However it appears that it's still hitting the rails route.

with the routes like this. I get this error:

> undefined method `user_path' for

config/routes.rb

```
# resources :users
# match ':id',             to: 'users#public_profile',    via: 'get', as: :public_profile
# match '/users/:slug',    to: 'users#show',              via: 'get', as: :profile
match '/users/*path', to: 'users#index', via: 'get'
```

with the routes like below I get this error in the console:

```
> GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/user_profile.html 404 (Not Found)

resources :users
match ':id',             to: 'users#public_profile',    via: 'get', as: :public_profile
match '/users/:slug',    to: 'users#show',              via: 'get', as: :profile
```

assets/javascripts/angular/app.js.coffee

```
angular.module("myapp", [
  "ngRoute"
  "templates"
]).config ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->
  console.log "app"
  $routeProvider.when "/users/:id",
    templateUrl: "user_profile.html"
    controller: "UserCtrl"

  $locationProvider.html5Mode true
  return
```

assets/javascripts/angular/controllers/users.js.coffee

```
angular.module("myapp").controller "UserCtrl", ($scope) ->
  console.log "controller"
  $scope.things = [
    "Angular"
    "Rails 4.1"
    "Working"
    "Together!!"
  ]
  return
```

templates/users/user_profile.html.erb

```
<h1>The Home View!</h1>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="thing in things">
    {{thing}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you do a server restart after changing your routes file?

Comment: I did. The errors above reflect what I saw after the restart.